# grails - send gsp template as mail using MimeMessage

Tags: email, grails, grails-2.0, mime-message

I'm making my own email service in grails because the mail plugin cannot meet my requirements.

Does anyone know how to set gsp template as content of MimeMessage. I want to pass a gsp template with parameters as email content like (view: 'sampleView/content', model: [....]).

this is my code

```
    def auth = new SMTPAuthenticator()
    def session = Session.getInstance(props, auth)
    session.setDebug(true);

    def msg = new MimeMessage(session)
    msg.setText(m_text)
    msg.setSubject(m_subject)
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email))
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(m_to))

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
    transport.connect(d_host, d_port, d_uname, d_password);
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
```

I already tried using PageRenderer but it's not working. the error is 'Cannot invoke method findViewByPath() on null object'. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you tell us how you use `PageRenderer`? I'm using `groovyPageRenderer.render(view: viewPath, model: model)`, which returns a `String`, and it's working very well.

Comment: i imported 'import grails.gsp.PageRenderer' then declare 'PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer = new PageRenderer()' because 'PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer' only returns null. then 'String s = groovyPageRenderer.render(view: "viewpath")'. error occurs. im using grails 2.4.5

Comment: Hmm, it should be `PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer` - I don't know why the injection doesn't work. Are you using it in a grails controller or service?

Comment: i find that strange too. im trying to call it inside a service